# C# How to write a function body that could be used as GetAverageAge(students, s => s.age)

Tags: c#, lambda

Say I have several ObservableCollections of different classes:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public int age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int age { get; set; }
    }

ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = ...;
ObservableCollection<Student> students = ...;
```

now I need a function to calculation the average age of these collections:

```
int employeeAveAge = GetAverageAge(employees, e => e.age);
int studentAveAge = GetAverageAge(students, s => s.age);
```

How to write the function body? Im not familiar with Action/Fun delegate, and somebody suggested me to pass a lambda as the function's parameter

well I don't use the build-in LINQ Average() because I want to learn the usage of passing lambda to function

Comment: I just dont know how to write such function, especially the arguments: GetAverageAge(Action a)? something like this?

Comment: Why do you want to get your average age as integer? I am sure, that in case of age, the fraction is really significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function would be something like this (untested):

```
public int GetAverageAge<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T,int> ageFunc)
{

   int accum = 0;
   int counter = 0;
   foreach(T item in list)
   {
      accum += ageFunc(item);
      counter++;
   }

   return accum/counter;
}
```

You could use the LINQ [`Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298366.aspx) method instead:

```
public int GetAverageAge<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T,int> ageFunc)
{
    return (int)list.Average(ageFunc);
}
```

Comment: Almost verbatim my answer!  But it should be Func<T, int>, not Func<T>.  And should return double and not do integer division.  Sorry to nitpick!

Comment: @Rock, but the age should not be double; as it looks odd that I am 17.5 years old.

Comment: @Waqas - May look strange, but that's what the question has.

Comment: @Oded: Good point.  Even if the desired result is an integer, integer division is still undesirable so we need rounding.  So we might as well use a double internally and Math.Round on the outside.

Comment: @Waqas well, My point was to ask how to write a function with a delegate argument, whether how to calculate average was not important...

Answer (score 3):

I'd do away with the function altogether and just use:

```
int employeeAge = (int)employees.Average(e => e.age);
int studentAge = (int)students.Average(e => e.age);
```

Edit:
Added the return and the cast to an int (Average returns a double).

Comment: Well ,suppose I don't want to use the build-in Average function, I want to know something inside

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
    double GetAverageAge<T>(IEnumerable<T> persons, Func<T, int> propertyAccessor)
    {
        double acc = 0.0;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var person in persons)
        {
            acc += propertyAccessor(person);
            ++count;
        }
        return acc / count;
    }
```

As an alternative, consider using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx), it already provides something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use LINQ for this?

```
employees.Select(e => e.age).Average()

students.Select(s => s.age).Average()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I Would do it this way for a normal list not sure about observable collection :

       List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
                                       {
                                           new Employee{age = 12},
                                           new Employee{age = 14}};
        Func<List<Employee>, int> func2 = (b) => GetAverageAge(b);

private static int GetAverageAge(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        return employees.Select(employee => employee.age).Average; //Thats quicker i guess :)
    }
```